# Failing to install Yeoman (Mac OSX)

Tags: macos, bash, yeoman

Attempting to install Yeoman on my mac, I first tried following command from the documentation...

`npm install -g yo`

Got an error:

`npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.`

I tried again with:

`sudo npm install -g yo`

but it fails half-way through. This is the feedback where it fails and it repeats this pattern for a lot of failed packages.

```
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/glob/.travis.yml'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Darwin 13.1.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "yo"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/vivid
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.7
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.21
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/glob/.travis.yml
npm ERR! fstream_path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/glob/.travis.yml
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. What fixed it for me was simply logging in as root first, using:

> `$ su`

Next, installing Yeoman worked like a charm:

> `$ npm install -g yo`

The big difference is the [logging in as root using `su`, instead of `sudo`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57040/what-is-the-difference-between-su-sudo-bash-and-sudo-sh).